# Tighter Bound on heapify

Tags: algorithm, heap

I want to calculate the tighter bound on heapify using siftdown approach so I proceeded as follows :

At each level `i`, each key on that level can go to leaf level `h` (where h is height of tree) in the worst case.
As there are 2<sup>i</sup> nodes at level i, so total work done is

∑<sub>0≤i≤h</sub> (h - i ) * 2<sup>i</sup>

But I couldn't proceed further. I know it has to come O(n) but I couldn't reach it. Please help me solving this.

Comment: Yes, But I tried it genuinely :P

Comment: Happy Mittal: please see answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

S = ∑<sub>0≤i≤h</sub> (h - i ) * 2<sup>i</sup>

S = h + 2(h - 1) + 4(h - 2) + ... + 2<sup>h - 1</sup>      ... (1)

Multiply both sides by 2,

2S = 2h + 4(h - 1) + 8(h - 2) + ... + 2<sup>h</sup>        ... (2)

Subtract from (1) from (2),

S = h -2h + 2 + 4 + 8 + …. + 2<sup>h</sup>

= -h – 1 + (1 + 2 + 4 + 8 +… + 2<sup>h</sup>  )

= (2<sup>h + 1</sup> - 1) – (h + 1)

[Note: 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + ... + 2<sup>h</sup> = (2<sup>h + 1</sup> - 1)

Since a complete binary tree of height h has between 2h and 2h + 1 nodes, the above sum is O(n) where n is the number of nodes in the heap.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little easier to see if instead of your `i` running from the top, you count from the bottom. So if we say `i` is the height from the bottom we transform your sum into:

∑ i * 2<sup>h-i</sup>

= 2<sup>h</sup> * ∑ i / 2<sup>i</sup>

= 2<sup>h</sup> * O(1)

= O(2<sup>logn</sup>) = O(n)

I swapped h with logn since this is a binary heap.

I'll justify why that sum is O(1):

The sum is a finite sum of the terms i/2<sup>i</sup>, so if we show convergence of the infinite sum (i-->infinite) then obviously every finite sum (i.e. for all n) will sum to less than that value (since all terms are positive). Meaning every finite sum is bounded by a constant, i.e. O(1).

We are left with just the proof that the infinite ∑ i / 2<sup>i</sup> converges. We can use a myriad of convergence tests, let's use the simple result that ∑ 1 / i<sup>2</sup> converges and show that for large enough i that will upper bound our sum:

We want to show that for large enough i:

i/2<sup>i</sup> < 1/i<sup>2</sup>

which happens iff i<sup>3</sup> < 2<sup>i</sup> which is true for, say, i > 10

QED

Comment: +1, although finite sums do not converge, they just are bounded themselves.

Comment: I was actually referring to @unkulunkulu's comment.

Comment: @Mitch, only a row or a sequence can converge, a finite sum is a number, it's static, you know. Or correct way of saying it is "sums of finite number of elements don't converge"?

Comment: @unkulunkulu: the notion of convergence doesn't technically apply to a finite sum (of non-infinite terms). As you say, they are a value. No need to invoke a limiting process. In addition this problem can be solved algebraically.

Comment: @Mitch, yes, isn't that what I was saying and you said it doesn't make sense?